# Error UTF8 - PYROCMS when setting SetEnv PYRO_ENV production in .htaccess

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

When running webside in production mode [  SetEnv PYRO_ENV production (.htaccess line 3) ], the titles of error utf8 which contain "là, và..." showing wrong (see the picture below). Could you help me how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Only suggestion I've got is to check your production DB/tables: are they set to UTF-8 encoding too?

Comment: oh, tyvm, it's fixed.